# LaTeX hyphenation different for inline optional hyphenation and explicit \hyphenation{...} definition

Tags: hyphenation

In a text, I get an overfull `hbox`. To avoid this, I define an optional hyphenation point:

```
bla bla bla un\-known bla bla bla
```

`pdflatex` indeed hyphenates the word at that point.
But when I declare the optional hyphenation point in the preamble like this

```
\hyphenation{un-known}
```

then `pdflatex` will NOT hyphenate there.
The reason seems to be that LaTeX still thinks that the typeset text does not look good enough with the line break after 'un-'.
But then why is the behavior different for the inline optional hyphenation to the optional hyphenation declared in the preamble?

Comment: Are you using multiple languages with babel?

Comment: If you can process your document with LuaTeX: include the package `lua-visual-debug` and you'll see the possible hyphenation points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding `\showthe\lefthyphenmin` so TeX stops and shows the value of this parameter. If it is set more than 2 then automatic hyphenation will never break after 2 letters. The default (for English) is 2, but some language setups change this.

Comment: No babel package used; but `\showthe\lefthyphemin` did the trick. It was set to 3. After setting it to 2 (simply use `\lefthyphenmin=2`), my optional hyphenation work as expected. Thanks for the hint.